# chroot process jail with arbitrary directory set as root on each run

Tags: linux, process, chroot, jail

I am trying to run a command that needs to be limited to one directory and is executed in a shell function from a web application.

My goal is to run that program but limit it to one directory. This directory will change each time I want to run the program and multiple instances need to be able to run on different directories at the same time.

I have looked at chroot and it seems that a file system needs to be explicitly created each time. I am looking for a more temporary solution that accepts the desired root directory and dose not require me to copy files all over the place or do weird mounting of things.

Comment: Just in case, in FreeBSD, you can create jails (https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails.html) [Poudriere](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-poudriere.html) use them extensively for temporary creating packages, probably that could give more ideas for what you want to accomplish

Answer (score -1):

What you most likely want is [containers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04).

A container takes milliseconds to start, and creates what is basically a complete chroot jail every time it runs. A command like `docker run --rm --volume /var/chroot/jail/whatever:/workdir ubuntu stat /workdir` will run `stat` on the chroot jail directory, with all environment being the latest Ubuntu release. It will then scrap the chroot jail. Running it again will create a whole new jail.

You will need to build your web application as a docker image on top of whatever jail you need (Ubuntu, CentOS etc.), which means adjusting your build system to create such an image.

Comment: The file system access is most important to me. I need to arbitrarily run the command on files in a specific folder limiting the application only using that one folder. Each time I am going to run it it will be against a different folder.

Comment: You can write a script to do a bunch of bind mounts to achieve that, but someone already wrote that - docker. I edited my answer, look into `--volume`.